# Visibility does not work

Tags: javascript, visibility, visible

So I have content that is hidden. And using one button, I want to make it visible. But it doesnt work

```
<table style="visibility:hidden;" id="viewevade">
        <tr>

        <td  class="form"width="25%">Period</td>
        <td  class="form"width="75%"> PeriodA </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="form">Inbound Call Date</td>
        <td class="form">Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="form">Input Date</td>
        <td class="form"> DateA</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="form">Reviewer</td>
        <td class="form">username</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="form">Topic</td>
        <td class="form">Topic A</td>
    </tr>

    <table width="100%" border=0 style="margin-top:20px;visibility:hidden;" id="vieweva">
    <tr>
    <td class="form" ><br>asdfjkl;asdfjkl;asdfjkl;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and I make a function:

```
function ViewEva()
{

document.getElementById("viewevade").style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById("vieweva").style.visibility='visible';
}
```

to use it in

```
 <button width="100%" onclick="ViewEva();">View Evaluation</button></td>
```

It doesnt work. Any help? Thanks b4

Comment: You are not closing the nested table

Comment: @LuisSieira that shouldn't be the problem

Comment: works fine for me : http://jsfiddle.net/o6eg330b/

Comment: @Luis. I have. still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this as a codepen here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjZMrO

Using your function:

```
function ViewEva()
{

document.getElementById("viewevade").style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById("vieweva").style.visibility='visible';
}
```

It seems to work fine. Do you have any errors in the JavaScript developer console of your browser?

EDIT: The form in the table contained an empty form post - this lead to the form being posted as it was displayed and the element appearing to show and immediately disappear.

```
<form action ="" method="post" onsubmit="">
```

Comment: It is visible for a while, and then hidden again. Nah, I dont know exactly. How can I check any error I may have?

Comment: Can you press f12 to get the developer console up? It depends on your browser but that works in most.

Comment: Here's a fuller answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Comment: I dont think  it is the problem. I try to run it in chrome, firefox and IE. still, it isvisible for about 1 second, and then hidden again

Comment: Could you refresh the codepen and try again? I have changed visibility to display:none

Comment: This behaviour doesn't seem to follow standards. Is your computer or browser experiencing other problems? Are you able to record a clip of this behaviour or otherwise take a log of the event firing? Try using console logging to make sure the event has fired.

Comment: Wait, it is visible a while and then it hides?

Comment: Is the console log refreshing as well?

Comment: That's a good question, does it hide or does the page refresh?

Comment: Oh damn. i didnt see something in the code. there is <form action ="" method="post" onsubmit="">. i think this is the problem.

Comment: That would cause the form to post as it was displayed I believe.

Comment: Thanks, i've updated my answer to reflect this, glad it's sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two things.

1. You are not including your script
2. Your HTML is wrong and your browser goes bananas

Here you have a [plunker working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9i1VjoiPus3tXRi1PLGa?p=preview)

Note both the `<script src='./script.js'></script>` and the

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <table width="100%" border=0 style="margin-top:20px;visibility:hidden;" id="vieweva">
      <tr>
        <td class="form" ><br>asdfjkl;asdfjkl;asdfjkl;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Your table cannot be direct child of the row, you have to put it in a column, and close the inner table